# php mysql insert values and select

Tags: php, mysql

how to insert variable and select in php

table1 1,2,3,4,5
table2 1,2,3,4

i want to insert table1 from table2 and table1.5 add variable 
(sorry idont speak english very well :)  )
query:

```
"INSERT INTO `table1` (`table1`.`5`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, ) 
 $variable, select `1`, `2`, `2`, `3`, `4` from `table2` where  `table2`.`3`=3; ";
```

Comment: Add more details on what you want to accomplish, what errors you got, or what's not working. And explain the weird column name scheme.

Comment: table1 column = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 tabel2 column 1,2,3,4, i want to add table2 column to tabl1 and table2.5 insert variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query syntax error is there. syntax is told you by **@Orel Eraki**...

So your SQL should be:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `table1` (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`) 
 SELECT `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, '$variable' FROM `table2` WHERE `table2`.`3`=3;";
```

I have changed the sequence of columns in `INSERT` list.

---

**Errors:**

1) `$variable` should be after `SELECT` (in select's column list), not before it.

2) in `SELECT` list you have written `column named as 2` two times... no of columns should be same as `INSERT`, and including `$variable` total goes to `6`. So I removed one `column 2`.

3) in `INSERT` after `column named as 4` you have a `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `INSERT and SELECT` on the same action on PHP.

But you meant `INSERT the SELECTED RESULT` than all you need is to do the following

```
INSERT INTO `Table-Destination`
SELECT * FROM `Table-Source` ...
```

Comment: thanks but at the same time  how add variable ?

Comment: @peace, Just add `$variable, ` before the asterisk so it will be `$variable, *`

Comment: in fact, I insert to table1 from table2 and then update table1.5=$variable but i dont want to use two query

Comment: @peace, Your post and replies are not clear. Try to exactly express what do you need and tried to do, and then repost.